# Wrap all default widget into div tag

Tags: widgets

I want wrap all default widget into a div tag, so i can add a suffix class to define style for each widgets

```
<div class="suffix-class">
 // widget
</div>
```

And in widget form, we have a input field to input this class.

It like module of joomla.

What can we do ? override all default widget ?

Comment: What is a _suffix class?_

Comment: Why do you need to add a class? There should already be markup enough to target the widget with style rules.

Comment: i want display it in different styles. and only change the class suffix instead of editing css

Answer (score 2):

In the [`register_sidebar()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebars) call in `functions.php`.

Look for `before_widget` and `after_widget` and modify as appropriate. The code below is the default usage.

```
'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
'after_widget'  => '</li>',
```

Answer (score 0):

I see this uestion is kind of old, but it also doesn't seem to have been answered. For anyone who wants to do this, I don't know how to do it via the template/code but there is a Wordpress plugin that lets you do it http://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/ . It works just like joomla so your widget will be like.

```
<div class="widget suffix-class">
 // widget
</div>
```

(Depending on your template) Hope this helps someone!